# PHP referencing nested array values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble returning a value out of a nested array...

the array dump looks like this

```
object(myObj)#1 (3) { 
["thing1"]=> string(5) "abcde" 
["thing2"]=> string(2) "ab"
["data"]=> array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "370" 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "370" 
    [1]=> string(26) "" 
    ["name"]=> string(26) "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 
    [2]=> string(0) "" 
    ["address"]=> string(0) "" 
    [3]=> string(4) "wxyz" 
    ["email"]=> string(4) "wxyz"
}
```

I want to get to "name" inside the "data" array....

I've tried

```
echo $myObj['data']['name'];
```

also

```
echo $myObj -> $data -> $name;
```

they always come back as UNDEFINED.

Comment: please explain why - yes it works, but I don't understand why.

Comment: simple, because it's a property but also an array, then you must call $instance->property_array['key']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
$myObj -> data['name'];
```

It sure is confusing. Let me explain.

The `var_dump` result you saw has two parts on them, one is object dump and another array .

```
object(myObj)#1 (3) {  <-- Starting point of object

["thing1"]=> string(5) "abcde"  <-- This is a property which has string value

["thing2"]=> string(2) "ab"     <-- This is a property which has string value


"data" here is a property of 
       object so you have to use
       $myObj -> data to access it

["data"]=> array(3) {           <-- But this is an array so you have to use 
                                    data[] to access its value
    [0]=> string(3) "370" 
    ["id"]=> string(3) "370" 
    [1]=> string(26) "" 
    ["name"]=> string(26) "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" 
    [2]=> string(0) "" 
    ["address"]=> string(0) "" 
    [3]=> string(4) "wxyz" 
    ["email"]=> string(4) "wxyz"
}
```

Comment: You don't like make comments yah

Comment: @Sam, It is answer to the problem and not a comment. And I was 12 seconds faster than you too :P :) ha ha

Comment: please explain why - yes it works, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @jpmyob, I have added explanation too. Read it. I have explained it further.